# Gradle add dependency on another source set via plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I've got a Gradle plugin that adds a `scratch` source set. I want classes defined in `src/main/java/` to be usable in `src/scratch/java`. I've figured out how to do this in the build file, but I'd like to have my plugin do this instead:

```
dependencies {
    scratchImplementation sourceSets.main.output
    //...
}
```

How can my plugin do this using the Gradle API?

Comment: Are you looking for this sort of thing?  https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/blob/371dfe02a7ec3eaef8e587112478339c12c8c727/src/main/groovy/org/grails/gradle/plugin/core/IntegrationTestGradlePlugin.groovy#L61-L65

Comment: Project conventions are being deprecated though, if your version of Gradle complains, you may want `project.dependencies.add("scratchImplementation", project.extensions.getByType(JavaPluginExtension).sourceSets.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME).output)` instead

Comment: That's the right sort of thing, but neither is quite working for me as-is. I didn't realize I needed to go through the JavaPluginExtension to get at this though, so that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I pieced this together from Jeff's example:
`project.dependencies.add(project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention).sourceSets.getByName("main").output);`

but aside from being deprecated in Gradle 7.2, Gradle doesn't seem to like the `add` call:

> Could not find method add() for arguments [main classes] on object of
> type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tim's suggestion using the extension instead of the convention avoids the deprecation. Initially I got an error when I tried it, but it seems to have cleared up now.

What I had found in the interim that also worked is:

```
        project.dependencies {
            // add dependency on main java code from scratch java code
            scratchImplementation project.extensions.getByType(JavaPluginExtension).sourceSets.getByName(SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME).output
        }
```

(though I'm not totally sure why)